# Ruby script error

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal

I've got a ruby script

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'highline/import'
require 'stringio'

#Change based on Semester
$term = '09'
$year = '2012'
$frequency = 4  #Number of Seconds between check requests

$agent = Mechanize.new
$agent.redirect_ok = true 
$agent.user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.11 Safari/535.19"
$agent.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

#Uber simway to colorize outputin
class String
def color(c)
    colors = { 
        :black   => 30, 
        :red     => 31, 
        :green   => 32,
        :yellow  => 33, 
        :blue    => 34, 
        :magenta => 35, 
        :cyan    => 36, 
        :white   => 37 
    }
    return "\e[#{colors[c] || c}m#{self}\e[0m"
end
end

#Logins, Gets the Courses, Returns Courses Obj with Name/URL/Tools for each
def login(username, password)

#Login to the system!
page = $agent.get("https://auth.vt.edu/login?service=https://webapps.banner.vt.edu/banner-cas-prod/authorized/banner/SelfService")
login = page.forms.first
login.set_fields({
    :username => username, 
    :password => password
})
if (login.submit().body.match(/Invalid username or password/)) then
    return false
else
    return true
end
end

#Gets Course Information
def getCourse(crn)  
begin
    courseDetails = Nokogiri::HTML( $agent.get(
        "https://banweb.banner.vt.edu/ssb/prod/HZSKVTSC.P_ProcComments?CRN=#{crn}&TERM=#{$term}&YEAR=#{$year}"
    ).body)
rescue
    return false #Failed to get course
end

#Flatten table to make it easier to work with
course = {}
dataSet = false

course[:title] = courseDetails.css('td.title').last.text.gsub(/-\ +/, '')
course[:crn] = crn

courseDetails.css('table table tr').each_with_index do |row|
    #If we have a dataSet
    case dataSet
        when :rowA
            [ :i, :days, :end, :begin, :end, :exam].each_with_index do |el, i|
                if row.css('td')[i] then
                    course[el] = row.css('td')[i].text
                end
            end
        when :rowB
            [ :instructor, :type, :status, :seats, :capacity ].each_with_index do |el, i|
                course[el] = row.css('td')[i].text
            end
    end

    dataSet = false
    #Is there a dataset?
    row.css('td').each do |cell|
        case cell.text
            when "Days"
                dataSet = :rowA
            when "Instructor"
                dataSet = :rowB
        end
    end
end

return course
end

#Registers you for the given CRN, returns true if successful, false if not
def registerCrn(crn)
#Follow Path
$agent.get("https://banweb.banner.vt.edu/ssb/prod/twbkwbis.P_GenMenu?name=bmenu.P_MainMnu")
reg = $agent.get("https://banweb.banner.vt.edu/ssb/prod/hzskstat.P_DispRegStatPage")
dropAdd = reg.link_with(:href => "/ssb/prod/bwskfreg.P_AddDropCrse?term_in=#{$year}#{$term}").click

#Fill in CRN Box and Submit
crnEntry = dropAdd.form_with(:action => '/ssb/prod/bwckcoms.P_Regs')
crnEntry.fields_with(:id => 'crn_id1').first.value = crn
crnEntry['CRN_IN'] = crn
add = crnEntry.submit(crnEntry.button_with(:value => 'Submit Changes')).body

if add =~ /#{crn}/ && !(add =~ /Registration Errors/) then
    return true
else
    return false
end
end

#Main loop that checks the availaibility of each courses and fires to registerCrn on availaibility
def checkCourses(courses)

requestCount = 0
startTime = Time.new
loop do
    system("clear")

    requestCount += 1
    nowTime = Time.new

    puts "Checking Availaibility of CRNs".color(:yellow)
    puts "--------------------------------\n"
    puts "Started:\t#{startTime.asctime}".color(:magenta)
    puts "Now:    \t#{nowTime.asctime}".color(:cyan)
    puts "Request:\t#{requestCount} (Once every #{$frequency} seconds)".color(:green)
    puts "--------------------------------\n\n"

    courses.each_with_index do |c, i|

        puts "#{c[:crn]} - #{c[:title]}".color(:blue) 
        course = getCourse(c[:crn]) 
        next unless course #If throws error

        puts "Availaibility: #{course[:seats]} / #{course[:capacity]}".color(:red)

        if (course[:seats] =~ /Full/) then
        else 
            if (registerCrn(c[:crn])) then
                puts "CRN #{c[:crn]} Registration Sucessfull"
                courses.slice!(i)

            else
                puts "Couldn't Register"
            end

        end

        print "\n"
    end

    sleep $frequency
end
end

#Add courses to be checked
def addCourses 
crns = []

loop do 
    system("clear")
    puts "Your CRNs:".color(:red)
    crns.each do |crn|
        puts "  -> #{crn[:title]} (CRN: #{crn[:crn]})".color(:magenta)
    end

    #Prompt for CRN
    alt = (crns.length > 0)  ? " (or just type 'start') " : " "
    input = ask("\nEnter a CRN to add it#{alt}".color(:green) + ":: ") { |q| q.echo = true }

    #Validate CRN to be 5 Digits 
    if (input =~ /^\d{5}$/) then

        #Display CRN Info
        c = getCourse(input.to_s)
        puts "\nCourse: #{c[:title]} - #{c[:crn]}".color(:red)
        puts "--> Time: #{c[:begin]}-#{c[:end]} on #{c[:days]}".color(:cyan)
        puts "--> Teacher: #{c[:instructor]}".color(:cyan)
        puts "--> Type: #{c[:type]} || Status: #{c[:status]}".color(:cyan)
        puts "--> Availability: #{c[:seats]} / #{c[:capacity]}\n".color(:cyan)

        #Add Class Prompt
        add = ask("Add This Class? (yes/no)".color(:yellow) + ":: ") { |q| q.echo = true }
        crns.push(c) if (add =~ /yes/)

    elsif (input == "start") then
        checkCourses(crns)
    end 
end
end


def main
system("clear")
puts "Welcome to CourseAdd by mil".color(:blue)

username = ask("PID ".color(:green) + ":: ") { |q| q.echo = true }
password = ask("Password ".color(:green) + ":: " ) { |q| q.echo = "*" }

system("clear")
if login(username, password) then
    addCourses
else
    puts "Invalid PID/Password"
    exit
end
end

main
```

but when I run ruby Untitled.rb it give me this error.

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- mechanize (LoadError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
from /Users/user/Desktop/Untitled.rb:3
```

What does this mean and how can I fix it? I'm not sure if I need to be doing this through an IDE or if terminal works. I'm brand new to ruby so I honestly have not a clue what the issue could be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install mechanize. In your terminal, type:

```
gem install mechanize
```

Retry your script when it finishes installing. If you have other gems that are missing, you can use the same command to install them.

```
gem install <gem name>
```

Comment: I did this then re-ran the program and got the same error. However It said I didn't have permissions to install mechanize so i did sudo gem install mechanize, entered my password, and it installed. I then re-ran it with the same error.

Comment: *** LOCAL GEMS ***

mime-types (1.22)
net-http-digest_auth (1.3)
net-http-persistent (2.8)

Comment: This ultimately was correct I just didn't have the correct ruby version installed, thank you

Comment: Yes, sorry. Just a side not for anyone viewing this in the future:
Install Homebrew if you are on a mac, often times the error is that you just don't have a gcc compiler or any way of dealing with gem installation.

Comment: I would also suggest installing rvm or rbenv so that you can have multiple version of ruby and different gemsets on the same computer. It's also worth noting that Bundler is typically used for managing gem dependencies for a ruby project.